# Geometry Nodes - Problem with Random Instance Rotation, when using Arc and Trim Curve nodes

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, instances

I have a problem with Random Instance Rotation, when using Arc / Trim Curves node. I'm trying to do something [similar in this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2JPtaK10MY&list=PLzJAo6mw1fKPa0TuImxKKghuxIAzys1jv&index=86&t=1s&ab_channel=Chong3D), but only with Geometry Nodes.

**Here is my node set up:**

[image]

Which results in this:

[image]

Arcs have different heights, which I want. **But I can't make them rotate randomly on individual Z axis at all.** The Random Rotation group does not work and I can't figure out why.

If I use Curve Line as Instance, without Trim group, I can create Arcs and then Rotate them randomly, like this:

[image]

But I don't get the individual height trim. It looks like this:

[image]

I have tried different combinations of the above and I am stuck. Is there a specific step that I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Here is Blend file:**

[image]

Comment: pls upload your file

Comment: i don't get it. The link IS about GN....!??

Comment: @Chris - yes, the YouTube tutorial is about the GN. But I want to recreate his set up completely in GeoNodes, without drawing any curves etc. Scatter some points > Instance Lines > Random Trim of those lines > Create Arcs > Random Rotation. But for some reason the Random Rotation is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is then you **convert to instance**, you convert all separated pieces into one big instance. Instead, try following:

You can rotate this blocks by tilting the curves and change height by scaling it:

[image]

I've also used **capture attribute** to make a random value generated per spline

Comment: thank you so much. This is simple and elegant solution and it does exactly what I need it to.

Comment: How do we randomize with rotation of these half cylinders inside a cube?.